# Enable Migrations from context on different assembly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

So basically I've two projects on the same solution. One of the projects its a **class library** where I have the all the Models and the Database Context class. The other one is a Web API. I want to use Nuget to Enable-Migrations on the Web API project but I always get the "No context type was found in the assembly Pr.WebApi.

So far I've tried:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Pr.ClassLibrary.Models
```

Any Ssuggestions?

Comment: You don't need to enable migrations on the webAPI project, just where your entity is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use *Enable-Migrations* in the Package Manager Console.  Make sure that the default project on the top of the package manager console is set to your class library.  That is the only project you need to enable the migrations on.

Answer (score 2):

When theres no data to store in a database in your WebAPI-Project, you dont need Entity Framework at all in this project. If you store data over your Class library, you can use the context from the class library project.

Answer (score 1):

*Enable-Migrations* should be invoked in your class library...